# VBA Code for if Duplicate values exist then

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel problem that I feel will have to be based off duplicates. Basically if duplicate values are found ("A:A") then somehow group them as a variable and only populate the matching rows if atleast 1 negative number exists in ("B:B"). The same will apply to non duplicates as well where they should only populate if a negative number exists in Column B but I feel that can be done easily via formula

I have tried a few things but the main problem is identifying the duplicates as their own variable. When I create a function that behaves purely off highlighted duplicates,this would apply to all duplicates regardless of their individual text. This would be much simpler if summed but that is not the case. Below is an example of what I am going for

```
Problem:

IDs        Trades
US9128     -500
US9128      750
EU9133      900
GD2104     -300
GD2104      150
FG5454      200

Expected:

IDs        Trades
US9128     -500
US9128      750
GD2104     -300
GD2104      150
```

Open to other routes to this problem

Comment: First you can sort the data, then do a frequency check using Pivot. After that delete which are occurring once.

Comment: you should post what you tried so we might be able to help you

Comment: You can use COUNTIFS() for this

Comment: Duplicates are irrelevant. What you write seems the same as  **IF** for any **ID** there is at least **one** negative **Trade**, then print all of those **ID**s and their matching trades.  You can create a helper column for that test, and filter on `TRUE`.  Or you can use a VBA solution of various types.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data is in column(A:B),Starting form row(1)
 Try this Macro

```
Option Explicit
Sub test_me()
Dim obj As Object
Dim x, k%
Dim R%, C%
 R = 2: C = 4
Dim lr%: lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
Dim i%, j%
Range("d2").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
Set obj = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
 For i = 2 To lr
     obj.Add Cells(i, 2).Value, Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = i + 1 To lr
         If Cells(j, 1) = Cells(i, 1) Then
          obj.Add Cells(j, 2).Value, Cells(j, 1).Value
         End If
        Next j
   x = obj.Count
   If x = 1 Then GoTo NEXT_I
    With Cells(R, C)
     .Value = obj.GetByIndex(0): .Offset(, 1) = obj.Getkey(0)
     .Offset(1) = obj.GetByIndex(x - 1): .Offset(1, 1) = obj.Getkey(x - 1)
    End With
    R = R + 2
NEXT_I:
   obj.Clear
 Next i
 Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Salim, thanks for the input. I like the route you were going but the macro only seemed to wipe all cells and give an error on line obj.Add Cells(i, 2).value, Cells(i, 1).Value

Comment: The file worked with me efficiently but I do not know how to raise it
Via the Internet Or how to raise it's picture
Give your Email to send it for you

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My email is:
boojangl@gmail.com

Comment: Great Mastro !! Do More Contribution !!

Comment: Thank U Regiz
could you explain for me How  to insert a picture in My answers
I tried several times but nothing happened

Comment: Hey Salim, haven't received that email just yet. Anyway you can send it when you have the time?